# How to take data from <input> in forms? Phoenix

Tags: apache-phoenix

I have a Phoenix application and in a page there is a form with input type text and input type submit. the form method is post. How can I take the data submitted from the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use form_for helper to do this.

Official Documentation is here 
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html

You should go through this to understand concept of form_for.
Let me know if you didn't get anything